# Change Angular 6 material specific table row dynamically by using index value

Tags: angular, indexing, angular-material, row

Got a index value of a particular row and need to change its default height which I get dynamically from other function. So I have both values separately, now is there any way by using index value `i`, can change particular row height?

Tried using below Javascript and it works fine for normal HTML manipulation but in angular (not desired result):

```
console.log("DynamicHeight: "+ dynHeight +"--> rowIndex: "+ rowIndexValue);

document.getElementById('dynamicTable').rows

    x[rowIndexValue].style.height=dynHeight
```

Looking for solution in angular 6, help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may get track of the index on cells definitions (`*matCellDef="let element; let index = index"`) and bind to `<td>` height property (`[style.height.px]="getRowHeight(index)"`):

**component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="column_id_1">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> $implicit </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index" [style.height.px]="getRowHeight(index)"> {{ element.column1 }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**component.ts**

```
  getRowHeight(index) {
    return index * 50; // do any calculations and return row height
  }
```

Notice that on this example I've bind directly to [style.height.px], but you could also bind to different properties or bind to height on different ways.

Also, if your calculations for height are simple, you could bind it directly on the template, without using a method for that.